# Angularjs-Accordion event trigger in page

Tags: javascript, jquery, ruby-on-rails, angularjs, jquery-ui

Hi I am a newbie in angularjs.
I am using a accordion in angularjs.It is used to display the list of channels I want to display i the site.

However I am having a issue.The problem is that I want to implement a accordion,when the page loads for the first time it should be show hidden,and when we click on the dropbox twice it should collapse.In short I want to implement a collapsible accordion.

How ever I am having some issues regarding the same.The below is the code which is used to implement the accordion.

```
$scope.openTab = function(e, object) {
        if(object.active){
            return false;
        }
        var thisElement = $(e.currentTarget);
        $scope.cleanObject($scope.tabs, 'active', false);
        object.active = true;
        $scope.openThread( object.discussions, object.discussions[0] );

         // Sometimes the tab opens off the screen, so we're adding some automatic scrolling
          // The setTimeout is to make sure we get the position after it's been animated (0.2s in CSS)
      setTimeout(function() {
        $('body, window').animate({scrollTop: thisElement.position().top - 50 + 'px'});
       }, 205)
            console.log("This is inside the tab")
        $('#accordion').accordion('activate', false );

    }

$scope.cleanObject = function(arr, param, value) {
        var len = arr.length;
        for(var i = 0; i < len; i++) {
            arr[i][param] = value;
        }
    } 

$scope.openThread = function(thisTabDiscussions, thread) {
        var $loadingIndicator = $('.discussionContents .loadingIndicator');

        // Set all threads as inactive
        $scope.cleanObject( thisTabDiscussions, 'active', false );

        // Activate the currently selected thread
        thread.active = true;
        thread.loading = true;                                   //check for accordion collapse event on click menu
        (function(thread){
            $timeout(function() {
                $scope.commentsExpanded = true;
            }, 250);
        })(thread);

        var indicatorCount = $loadingIndicator.get().length;
        for(var i = 0; i < indicatorCount; i++) {
            var $thisElement = $( $loadingIndicator[i] ),
            childrenCount = $thisElement.children().length;
            if(!childrenCount) {
                loading('show', {element: $thisElement});
            }
        }

        $scope.loadDiscussionThread(thread);

        // Set the commentsExpanded flag properly
        var openTabIndex = $scope.tabs.indexOf(thisTabDiscussions);
        if( openTabIndex != -1 && $scope.tabs[ openTabIndex ].active ) {  // the code is required to display the discussion comments
            $scope.commentsExpanded = true;
        }
        $('#accordion1').accordion({
            collapsible: true,
            autoHeight: false,
            active: false
        });

    }
```

I have also tried to implement the below with the help of jquery in the program but it is not working;-

```
 $('#accordion1').accordion({
            collapsible: true,
            autoHeight: false,
            active: false
        });
```

I have written the following code for accordion:-

```
 $scope.openNotification = function(selector_id) {
    var parentElement = ( selector_id ? $('#' + selector_id) : $('.discussionConfirmation') ),
    adjustElements = parentElement.children('li').children('.dc_check, .dc_close'),
    totalHeight = parentElement.outerHeight();

    adjustElements.height( totalHeight );
    parentElement.fadeIn().slideDown();
    setTimeout( function() {
        $scope.closeNotification(null, parentElement);
    }, 3000);
  }

  $scope.closeNotification = function(e, element) {
    if(e) {
        e.preventDefault();
        var thisElement = $(e.currentTarget),
        parentElement = thisElement.parent().parent();
    } else {
        parentElement = element;
    }

    parentElement.slideUp().fadeOut();
  }
```

Please help me with this.Thanks a lot

Answer (score 0):

If you want just collapsable effect no need to reinvent the wheel. Use the bootstrap. It goes well with angularjs and save you a lot of time.
I hope that [this_link](http://getbootstrap.com/javascript/#collapse) will help you

Ok. To HTML you need to add next code (or something like next code :) ):

```
<div class="panel panel-default">
 <div class="panel-heading" role="tab" id="headingOne">
  <h4 class="panel-title">
    <a data-toggle="collapse" ng-click="yourFunction" data-parent="#accordion" href="#collapseOne" aria-expanded="true" aria-controls="collapseOne">
       Item #1
    </a>
  </h4>
</div>
<div id="collapseOne" class="panel-collapse collapse in" role="tabpanel" aria-labelledby="headingOne">
  <div class="panel-body" id="body-accordion1">
    body text body text body text
  </div>
</div>
```

Notice, that attr **aria-expanded="true"** tells you, that your accordion body will automatically expand. 
Next what you need is add in angularjs controller function like this (if accordion content you get from the server):

```
$scope.yourFunction = function(){
  var bodyAccordion = $('#body-accordion1')
  bodyAccordion.append( "<div>Your text or whatever yor want</div>" );
}
```

and the last part - add listener onclick or add ng-click (angular directive) to html, like in my example. Good luck)

Comment: @james-schermann..I am using bootstrap library for the project..However please help me how to use it in the above case

Comment: Ok, i have edit my answer. If you have some question please aks me)

Comment: ...Sigh. It would be nice to see any answers relating to Angular not pointing to BootStrap. It's a little hard to take it as a serious alternative and replacement to jQuery when everyone's answer when it comes to creating new UI components is "You should use Bootstrap".